# C#: Creation of a Google Map with a line?

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

after three days of trying I'm near giving it up..
I try to use the Google Maps API to create a map with a longer line formed by several points. Unfortunately not even uploading a XML file worked out for me (Though I successfully authorized myself with my Google account).

Can someone please give me help and post a C#/VB code (snippet) on how to create a map and draw a line on it? Thanks for you help!

Norbert

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript API for Google map, here is a sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Polyline Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 3,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
        new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
    ];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

   flightPath.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to clarify that I need to build the map out of C# code, not a website. Thanks, though!

Comment: Okay. For me I was showing it on a webform and I loaded the map using Google javascript API for MAP and could show it.